# How to Pack two executables into one executable, then extract and run them?

Tags: windows, exe, extract, packing

In Windows, what software is there for me to use so I can pack two executable files into one other executable, and then how do I make this other executable extract the two executables and run them both at the same time ? 
In other words, how do I code and create the **main** executable so that upon running it, it extracts the two other executables from itself and runs both of them, preferably in c++ ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found one answer. I can use **ExeFusion**.